# how to use the domain name ended with .in not .com or .org as redirect url of google oauth

Tags: google-oauth, nodes

> **how to use .in extension redirect url in google oauth??**

I am trying to add the my domain name which is with .in extension like abcd.def.in to redirect url of auth but not logging in to the google account what is the better solution to add my domain??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "but not logging in to the google account"?

Comment: I am using google signIn. My website domain name is abcd.def.in (example) In google sign API it is not authorising the abcd.def.in  kind of redirecting url ,How can I make it authorise.